# Image from ajax request doesn't show up on carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, owl-carousel

Hi I seem to stumble with my code, I have an ajax request from a php file which gets its' thumbnail_url that is fetching from an api.
My problem is in my js and carousel. What I want to achieve is that I want to append the pulled images from ajax to owl carousel.

```
<title>Ajax Preview</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://syncslider-ehnoxx07.c9users.io/Working_imgs_ajax/main.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://syncslider-ehnoxx07.c9users.io/With_slick/owl-carousel.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://syncslider-ehnoxx07.c9users.io/With_slick/owl-theme.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://syncslider-ehnoxx07.c9users.io/With_slick/owl-carousel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://syncslider-ehnoxx07.c9users.io/With_slick/owl-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://syncslider-ehnoxx07.c9users.io/With_slick/carousel.js"></script>

  <style>
  #owl-demo .item{
  background: #a1def8;
  padding: 30px 0px;
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
  color: #FFF;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
}
.prevImg{
    visibility:visible !important;
    display:block !important; 
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="owl-example" class="owl-carousel">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My ajax

```
 $(function() {
        var $data = $('#owl-example');
        $.ajax({
         type:'GET',
         dataType:'json',
         url:'https://syncslider-ehnoxx07.c9users.io/Working_imgs_ajax/preview-template.php',
         success: function (data) {
          //pull data object to get thumbnail_urls.
          for(var i=0 ; i<data.length ; i++){
            console.log(data);
          $data.append('<div class="item"><img class="prevImg" src=' + data[i].thumbnail_url + '></div>');
         }
         }
     });
    });
```

Comment: what do you get when try to `console.log(data[i].thumbnail_url)`?, is it correct src?. and please be more specific while descriping the problem, as now i don't know if the div wasn't appended or it is but the img not showing?

Comment: @AyaSalama I get objects and inside of it was objects of site_name, prev_url , thumbnail_url etc

Comment: please answer the second question and descripe what is happening

Comment: @AyaSalama yea sorry about that the srcs are correct the imgs don't show as well. All I got is a blank document even on the html body when I inspect element it there's nothing appended to it.

Comment: not sure if this is what causing the problem but try to add "" in your src `$data.append('<div class="item"><img class="prevImg" src="' + data[i].thumbnail_url + '"></div>')`

Comment: and please try `console.log(data[i].thumbnail_url)` and tell me what is logged

Answer (score 0):

You need to reinit `owlCarousel` container with new items.
Make sure you are getting proper images url in `data[i].thumbnail_url`.
Replace JS with below code.

Actual code to re-init carousel with new items

```
var owl = $(".owl-carousel").data('owlCarousel');
$data.append(html);
owl.reinit(OWL_OPTIONS);
```

Working demo [**JS fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/s10bgckL/840/), there are 2 default items in carousel after the interval of 2 seconds other 2 items will be added to previous carousel.

If you want to replace whole carousel items with new one then replace 
`$data.append(html);` with `$data.html(html);`
Replace with new [**item fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/s10bgckL/841/)

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var $data = $("#owl-example"),
                OWL_OPTIONS = {
                    autoPlay: 3000, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds
                    dots: true,
                    items: 2,
                    itemsDesktop: [1199, 3],
                    itemsDesktopSmall: [979, 3]
                };
        $data.owlCarousel(OWL_OPTIONS);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'https://syncslider-ehnoxx07.c9users.io/Working_imgs_ajax/preview-template.php',
            success: function (data) {
                //pull data object to get thumbnail_urls.
                var html = '';
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    html += '<div class="item"><img class="prevImg" src=' + data[i].thumbnail_url + '></div>';
                }
                setTimeout(function () {
                    var owl = $(".owl-carousel").data('owlCarousel');
                    $data.append(html);
                    owl.reinit(OWL_OPTIONS);
                }, 2000);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Still the same nothing is appended on my html and still blank.
My console has no errors or warnings just a successful Get request,

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $(function()
    {
        $('#owl-example').owlCarousel();
        $.ajax({ type:'GET', dataType:'json',
            url:'ajax.php',
            success: function (data)
            {
                var html = '';
                var i=0;
                var length=data.length;
                while(i<length)
                {
                    //alert(data[i].preview_url);
                    html+="<div><img src='"+data[i]+"'></div>";
                    i++;
                }
                $("#owl-example").html(html);
            }
        } );

    });

</script>
```

Hope this helps.